# Facebook Javascript SDK Autologin & Tokens

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, token, autologin

I am using the Facebook login as an authentication for my PhoneGap application - once a user logs in, their data is retrieved from my database to display information. I am not using the SDK for any other purpose.

I have the Facebook auto login working fine - it retrieves an authResponse and my Facebook information. Since the access token changes with each login, what can I use to store locally and in my database to authenticate the user on my server for future logins?

Here is a flow that I think *could* work...

1. User sees logs in screen and enters Facebook credentials
2. Facebook securely validates and returns user information & access token
3. The app uses localStorage to store user email and access token
4. For future autologin, the localStorage values are used as email/password

I feel like this cannot be the correct answer, however.

Comment: Yes, localStorage should never be used for saving sensitive information like password and customer data

Comment: @MandeepSingh I agree - what do you propose?

Comment: The access token is only valid for a few hours

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution - I was confused about storing passwords on my database to fetch user information. Rather, these are the correct steps:

1. Use Facebook SDK to handle the login and retrieve the authResponse
2. Update the user table in my database with the temporary access token and retrieve user's information
3. For every POST or GET the user wishes to perform, I will match the FB.getLoginStatus() results from the database's access token (the check will be done server side)
4. If the tokens match, perform requests. Otherwise, force the user to login again.

Comment: But token exists only for few hours, you have hit again for new token

Comment: Correct - repeatedly opening up the app will create new tokens and the app is working fine without a forced login every time.